# prism switch between views in the same region

Tags: prism

I have a region named "ActiveModule" and want to re-use it with different views, for example you press the search button and I show the search view in there, etc. etc.

The only way I can ATM do that is to deactivate all the active views in that region and then activate the view I like, this is a bit dirty, is there a "viewManager" or something similar I can use?

Answer (score 4):

If your region is a ContentControl or derives from ContentControl, then there can only be one active view at a time, and you only need to activate the search view on the region.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider to use a type of contentControl that is able to show multiple views?
For example you can use a TabControl like this:

```
<TabControl Name="MainRegion" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
```

You can now add more than one view to the region. Use `INavigationAware` and `IActiveAware` interfaces from Prism to be able to do navigation on the views (activate them, find the correct view etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `IRegionManager`, you can remove all of the views whose types you recognize and then add your own.

```
    foreach (var view in _regionsManager.Regions["MyRegion"].Views.ToArray())
    {
        if (view is MyType ||
            view is MyOtherType)
            _regionsManager.Regions["MyRegion"].Remove(view);
    }

    _regionsManager.AddToRegion("MyRegion", typeof(MyView));
```

Its by no means ideal, but it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge what you are doing is the only way, theoretically in SCSF the top most view was activated by the framework. You could create ur own ViewManager or a ShowViewService equivalent to get this done. MAtter of fact, thats what i have done!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you laid out your framework but if you are using navigation related framework you can simply call

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, new Uri("your target view" + parameters, UriKind.Relative));
```

the above line will take care of deactivating other views in the region.

Otherwise if you do view discovery or view injection you can use the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862824/activating-views-in-regions-in-prism)

```
region.Activate(view);
```