# Activating views in regions in Prism

Tags: c#-4.0, mef, prism-4

I have problem that I don't seem to be able to solve. I have a created a test project, using MEF and Prism4. I've created a test project where I have 2 views and each of them register themselves inside a region, and also a button in another region. When the button is clicked, I want the view of change to the correct view. The code I think is wrong is below, anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong here ?

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, typeof(Views.Module1View));

        Button button = new Button() { Content = "Module1" };
        button.Click += (o, i) =>
        {
            var region = this.regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion];
            if (region != null)
            {
                region.Activate(typeof(Views.Module1View));
            }
        };

        regionManager.AddToRegion(RegionNames.NavigationRegion, button);
    }
```

I get the following error ...

```
The region does not contain the specified view.
Parameter name: view
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it - amazing what a good nights sleep will do! I had to get the view from the ServiceLocator.

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, () => 
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Views.Module2View>());

        Button button = new Button() { Content = "Module2" };
        button.Click += (o, i) =>
        {
            var view = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Views.Module2View>();

            var region = this.regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion];
            if (region != null)
            {
                region.Activate(view);
            }             
        };

        regionManager.AddToRegion(RegionNames.NavigationRegion, button);
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to get the view from ServiceLocator. You can also use region.GetView( regionName )